# template programming

Tags: c++

I am new to template programming. I have a question like this

```
A.process(B)
```

where A is a template parameter.

Is it fine for me to set B as a template parameter as well? By that I would be able to let different type A objects to process different type of objects B. B normally would not be used polymorphically in run time.

Thanks.

Comment: The question may well be closed as it's very vague... please try to be more precise; perhaps include some code where you've attempted to do what you want and explain what aspects work or don't work as you'd like, or the compiler errors you get.  You might also try providing the rest of a minimal program that would use the functionality: `A.process(B)` doesn't convey much, as some statements are contradictory (e.g. fine...to set B as template parameter?  Literally, that would mean B was an integral constant, but later you talk of "type of objects B", indicating B's a type).

Answer (score 3):

**If** I understand your requirement, then yes - you can do something like:

```
template <typename A, typename B>
void fn(A& a, B& b)
{
    ...other code...
    a.process(b);
    ...other code...
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure that that's the requirement.  IMO, he/she wants a member function template `template <typename B> A::process(B b)`, but that's also parameterisable over `A`.

Comment: @Oli: "also parameterisable over A" - would that be double dispatch?  If not, I'm pretty sure I won't be the one giving the answer :-).

Comment: That's my understanding, yes!

Comment: @Oli: well then, until the OP confirms I'll just offer the canned: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch

Answer (score 0):

Well, since we're all speculating on the meaning of the question, I'll offer what I think is in mind here. In the same way that one can create a template like -

```
template<typename T, std::size_t size = 50> struct fixed_array {
private:
  T a[size];
};
```

...with "size" being an instance of an existing type, and not the name of a type, I think the questioner wants to know if one can do something like the following -

```
struct A_type {
  ...    // whatever constitutes this class plus overloaded methods like ...
  void process(int B) {
    std::cout << "int overload: " << B << std::endl;
  }
  void process(const char* B) {
    std::cout << "string overload: " << B  << std::endl;
  }
} A; // an actual instance of A_type

template<A_type A, int B> void foo() {
  A.process(B);      // will call the int overload
}

main() {
  foo<A, 3>();       // produces the output "int overload: 3"
}
```

The answer is "no". At least, not as formulated above. There are restrictions on non-type template parameters that are well-summarized here: [template parameters](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters). The type of such a parameter has to conform to *LiteralType*, which includes references. So by tweaking the function definition as follows -

```
template<A_type& A, int B> void foo() {
  A.process(B);      // will call the int overload
}
```

Now we're good-to-go, and it satisfies the questioner's requirement to produce a template (class or function) in which A and B, both of which are clearly instances and not types, are both parameterized at compile time, such that `A.process(B)` can be understood and compiled. By C++20, there are a set of rules that allow the original formulation of `foo` if `A_type` obeys a number of conventions, but that's all covered in the above link. NOTE: while *LiteralType* entities can include references, the object of those references must be statically defined, either in the global declaration area or declared with the keyword `static`. The compiler must know the value at compile time, and it must be impossible to change at run-time. So for example the following -

```
template<A_type& A, const char* B> void bar() {
  A.process(B);
}
```

this `main` definition will not compile -

```
main() {
  bar<A, "hello">();
}
```

but the following will -

```
const char* h_string = "hello";

template<A_type& A, const char*& B> void bar() { // note the switch to reference
  A.process(B);
}

main() {
  bar<A, h_string>();  // will produce output "string overload: hello"
}
```

as will -

```
main() {
  static const char* h_string = "hello";
  bar<A, h_string>();
}
```

For reasons I can't quite work out, even using `double` in stead of `int` didn't work in the version of clang I tried this on, so it may not be as flexible a trick as the questioner would like. That being said, there are without doubt many other approaches to solving the questioner's higher level problem.